# Add Color to syncfusion ColorpickerPalette control

Tags: c#, wpf-controls, colorbox, syncfusion

i will add color to standard color list in syncfusion ColorPickerPalette control.
i write code:

```
 ColorPickerPalette  Palette=new ColorPickerPalette();
    Palette.stdColorCollection=new ObservableCollection<ColorGroupItem>();
    ColorGroupItem ColorItem=new ColorGroupItem();
    ColorItem.HeaderName="No Color";
    ColorItem.Color=Brushes.Transparent;
    Palette.stdColorCollection.Add(ColorItem);
```

But this color dont show in Palette.

Answer (score 0):

Try if a theme is getting applied:

```
Palette.Themes = PaletteTheme.Apex;
```

if it doesnt work, check if you have properly added the palette to the parent control:

```
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(colorpicker);
```

Let me know if it works. Otherwise we'll think of other things. :)

CHEERS !!!

Comment: this don't work.i am newbie .please more decription for working to Color.